# How to display like below explaination in freemarker

Tags: logic, freemarker

**Input**

```
ListingName = abhay, hkm, Himanshu
ListingAddress = Delhi, Noida, Agra
```

This can have many values not only 3

**Output**

```
abhay   
Delhi

hkm   
Noida

Himanshu   
Agra
```

Please help me how to do this in FreeMarker.

Comment: Can you show us some code, what have you tried until now?

Comment: I have list format but not able to display both in the same as output... Only one data I am able to show I need to show both hand by hand

Comment: Does not help, show us some code, what you are trying here and what exactly u r getting, format the code and output as well

Comment: The output and input in have given in discription rest i myself not able to figure out what need to be done to get that ooutput

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the array with a <#list>. This loop is going through ListingName and using the ListingName's index to retrieve corresponding address from the second array.

```
<#assign ListingName = ["abhay", "hkm", "Himanshu"]>
<#assign ListingAddress = ["Delhi", "Noida", "Agra"]>

<#list ListingName as listing>
  ${listing}
  ${ListingAddress[listing?index]}

</#list>
```